# Is it possible to emulate the behaviour of StateT without the use of custom types?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, state-monad, io-monad

If we have the following two functions, add and subtract, it is simple to chain them to run a series of calculations on an input:

```
add :: Int -> State Int ()
add n = state $ \x -> ((),x+n)

subtract :: Int -> State Int ()
subtract n = state $ \x -> ((),x-n)

manyOperations :: State Int ()
manyOperations = do
    add 2
    subtract 3
    add 5
    --etc


result = execState manyOperations 5
--result is 9
```

If we want to print out the state after each calculation is done, we use the `StateT` monad transformer:

```
add :: Int -> StateT Int IO ()
add n = StateT $ \x -> print (x+n) >> return ((),x+n)

subtract :: Int -> StateT Int IO ()
subtract n = StateT $ \x -> print (x-n) >> return ((),x-n)

manyOperations :: StateT Int IO ()
manyOperations = do
    add 2
    subtract 3
    add 5

main = runStateT manyOperations 5
-- prints 7, then 4, then 9
```

Is it possible to replicate this "combined computation and printing" without `StateT` or any custom datatypes?

As far as I know it's possible to do all the processes that `MaybeT IO a` can do using `IO (Maybe a)`, but it seems like that's because it's just nested monads. On the other hand, `StateT` might not have an alternative because `s -> (a,s)` is fundamentally different to `s -> m (a,s)`

I can only see two directions the code could go: using `State Int (IO ())` or `IO (State Int ())`, but both of these seem nonsensical given the implementation of `StateT`

I believe it is impossible. Am I correct?

*Note: I know this is completely impractical, but I couldn't find any solution after some hours of work, which means I'm correct or my skills aren't enough for the task.*

Comment: Impossible is nothing...but why do you want to do this? That's what `StateT` is *for*. You could always just pass around the `Int` state explicitly , and do everything in `IO ()` alone...

Comment: You can completely avoid those data types by using `s -> IO (a, s)` directly, substituting for `a` and `s` appropriately. It definitely won't be as nice though.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `State` is defined in terms of `StateT` and not the other way.

Comment: @DavidYoung Turn that into an answer!

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do all the plumbing yourself. Monads don't add anything new to Haskell, they just enable a ton of code reuse and boilerplate reduction. So anything you can do with a monad, you can laborously do by hand.

```
manyOperations :: Int -> IO ()
manyOperations n0 = do
    let n1 = n0 + 2
    print n1
    let n2 = n1 - 3
    print n2
    let n3 = n2 + 5
    print n3
```

If the amount of repetition in the above function is too much for you (it is for me!) you *could* try to reduce it with a 'combined computation and printing' function but at this point you're bending over backwards to avoid `StateT`.

```
-- a bad function, never write something like this!
printAndCompute :: a -> (a -> b) -> IO b
printAndCompute a f = let b = f a in print b >> return b

-- seriously, don't do this!
manyOperations n0 = do
    n1 <- printAndCompute (+2) n0
    n2 <- printAndCompute (-3) n1
    n3 <- printAndCompute (+5) n2
    return ()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is quite what you're looking for, but you could define an operation which takes a stateful operation that you alread have, and prints out the state after performing the operation -

```
withPrint :: (Show s) => State s a -> StateT s IO a
withPrint operation = do
    s <- get
    let (a, t) = runState operation s
    liftIO (print t)
    put t
    return a
```

and then do

```
manyOperations :: StateT Int IO ()
manyOperations = do
    withPrint (add 2)
    withPrint (subtract 3)
    withPrint (add 5)
    -- etc
```

This doesn't *avoid* using `StateT` but it abstracts out the conversion of your regular, non-IO state operations into IO-ful state operations so you don't have to worry about the details (aside from adding `withPrint` when you want the state to be printed.

If you don't want the state printed for a particular operation, you could define

```
withoutPrint :: State s a -> StateT s IO a
withoutPrint operation = do
    s <- get
    let (a, t) = runState operation s
    put t
    return a
```

which is actually equivalent to

```
import Control.Monad.Morph

withoutPrint :: State s a -> StateT s IO a
withoutPrint = hoist (\(Identity a) -> return a)
```

using `hoist` from `Control.Monad.Morph` to transform the monad underlying `StateT` from `Identity` to `IO`.

Comment: Abstracting the printing might be a helpful feature, but it's not what I'm looking for. Thanks for the input, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can completely avoid those data types by using `s -> IO (a, s)` directly, substituting for `a` and `s` appropriately. It definitely won't be as nice though.

It would look something like this:

```
-- This makes StateIO s act as a shorthand for s -> IO (a, s)
type StateIO s a = s -> IO (a, s)

add :: Int -> StateIO Int ()
add n = \x -> print (x+n) >> return ((),x+n)

sub :: Int -> StateIO Int ()
sub n = \x -> print (x-n) >> return ((),x-n)

manyOperations :: StateIO Int ()
manyOperations =   -- Using the definition of (>>=) for StateT
  \s1 -> do        -- and removing a lambda that is immediately applied
      (a, s2) <- add 2 s1
      (a, s3) <- sub 3 s2
      add 5 s3

result :: IO ((), Int)
result = manyOperations 5
```

The state has to be explicitly threaded through all the operations. This is a major gain we get from using the `StateT` datatype: the `(>>=)` method of its `Monad` instance does all this for us! We can see from this example, though, that there is nothing magical going on in `StateT`. It's just a very nice way of abstracting out the threading of state.

Also, the relationship between `StateT` and `State` is the opposite of the relationship between `MaybeT` and `Maybe`: `State` is defined in terms of `StateT`. We can see that fact expressed in [this type synonym](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#State):

```
type State s = StateT s Identity
```

It is a transformer over [the `Identity` type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.2.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html#t:Identity) (which has the trivial `Monad` instance).